# Microsoft Graph Toolkit doesn't work - not sure why

Tags: microsoft-graph

I'm new to Microsoft Graph Toolkit but i can't get it to work inside my SharePoint site

I'm getting error
[image]

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/mgt/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>
<mgt-msal-provider client-id="XXXXXXXX"
                        login-type="redirect" 
                        scopes="user.read,people.read" 
                        redirect-uri="URL OF THE SHAREPOINT SITE I HAVE THE SCRIPT LOADING" 
                        authority=""> 
    </mgt-msal-provider> 
    <mgt-login></mgt-login>
    <mgt-people-picker></mgt-people-picker>
```

MY CONFIG ABOVE

Any ideas what i'm missing?

Comment: Is this code in a SharePoint Framework web part? If not, how are you getting it into the page?

Comment: Hi Rob, Its isn't in a spfx webpart. I'm using the modern script editor webpart.
Thanks